# How do I turn off exception translation in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-roo

JPA code in Roo's entities have their exceptions automatically translated to Spring data exceptions. As I am porting pure JPA code (moving DAO code into the entities as seems to be standard with Roo's rich domain model), I'd rather not modify the catch blocks for Spring's proprietary exceptions.

Can someone tell me how to turn this off in my entities? The [Spring JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6275) suggests this is possible, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the following line in your appcontext doesn't work?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

I haven't found any traces in roo source to such roo functionality.

Comment: I'm afraid that none of my appContext files (main, security, or servlet) have that bean configured. My hunch is that it's done somewhere behind the scenes via AspectJ.

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-315 - seems like the functionality was totally removed, but I don't really understand where is it implemented then, try to contact the Roo developers imho.